# Android APP migrates from GCM to FCM. Old GCM tokens do not work

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

The document from Google says:

> GCM tokens retrieved via GoogleCloudMessaging.register() or
>   InstanceID.getToken() will continue to work in FCM without any
>   modification or renewal.

But when I update my APP to FCM. The old GCM token which stores in my Server does not work anymore. When I tried to send a push message, the Google Message server response the error message, not registered. Does anyone ran into the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from the documentation of [GCM and FCM FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq):

Will your existing GCM tokens and token handling still work?

> Your **GCM** and **FCM** registration tokens are mutually interchangeable; you
>   can send to existing GCM tokens through the FCM HTTP server APIs. For
>   GCM and FCM token handling, remember:
>
> - If you store and send to specific tokens, **be sure to implement the token refresh method** to ensure your tokens are always up to date
> - iOS devs should avoid calling `.getToken(authorizedEntity,scope)` unless there is a need to enable multiple senders. Use
>     `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` instead.